# Execute Process Task can't run executable file .bat on Visual Studio 2010 version

Tags: batch-file, ssis, executeprocesstask

I am trying to create a SSIS package using executable file .bat but the Execute Process Task can't run executable file .bat on Visual Studio 2010 version. It's running fine on the previous versions but not on the 2010 versions. Any idea if I need to do some settings change or anything else ?
It's giving me the error

> The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

Comment: Does it use NET Framework and is targeting a newer version on an OS which is using an earlier version?

Comment: No.. It's using a vbs file in it and the OS remains same throughout.

Comment: What I meant was in the compilation, the compiler of the newer VS will probably by default use a newer .NET

Comment: So, what should I do ?

Comment: You can change it from the default to lets say .NET 4 in the settings. Double click on your project, _(Solution Explorer)_ > Click "Compile" > Click "Advanced Compile Options" > Change the Target Framework. BTW this is just a guess, there could be any number of reasons for this message.